# How to iterate android app subprojects belonging to a build.gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I found this example in gradle docs.

```
configure(subprojects.findAll {it.name != 'tropicalFish'}) {
    hello << {println '- I love to spend time in the arctic waters.'}
}
```

I hoped to modify it like this, but can't seem to find my way out.

```
configure(subprojects.findAll {it.hasAndroidPluginApplied}) {
    task doSomethingAboutIt << { println 'doing something with android projects' }
}
```

Comment: The configure 'code' appears to execute before subprojects are configured, so even though they are considered - they still have nothing applied yet.